# Remove entities and remove relationships on Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

I´m using EF databaseFrist and creating a model, now having a problem trying to understand how to delete an entity or a relationship.

Lest say a have and Table `"A"` and a Table `"B"`, and a `"a_b"` table that relates `A` and `B` by id (many to many), `a_b` only has `id_A` and `id_B`, so there is no entity `a_b` created on the model. `A` has a `list<B>` and `B` has a `list<A>`, i need to know how can i perform the next functions:

```
-Remove all B entities related to A, it means delete the rows of B.
-Remove only the relationships of A to B, so all entities still exist on DB but they are dissociated.
-Delete A and remove all B related as well (remove entities from DB). 
-Delete A and preserve all B entities.
-How will it change if a_b has any other property so it becomes an entity
```

thanks for your time.

pd: I´m using Lambda syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell EF on DB First model creation to expose all primary and foreign-key properties in the entities. What it means to you  is that you can query separately by querying for child objects to a parent by using the foreign-key property of the child object linked to the parent object's primary key. You can delete each child object to the parent by the child's primary-key property value to remove the relationship between parent and child. You can delete the parent if no child object is linked to the parent. That's if one is  doing things normally in a deletion process using EF where one takes complete control of the deletion process.

So, you can kind of do something like that.